# How to insert tags in html code with bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have the following html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   ...

<main>
   <div class=postLink>
      <a href="asdfa.html"> Write your title here</a>
      <div id="description"> Write the description of the post. It will show in the index.</div>
     <div id="datePost">19-06-2017</div>
     <div id="tags">
     </div>
  </div>

 <div class=postLink>
     <a href="aasdf.html"> Write your title here</a>
     <div id="description"> Write the description of the post. It will show in the index.</div>
     <div id="datePost">19-06-2017</div>
     <div id="tags">
     </div>
 </div>
 ...

</main>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to insert the tags in div called tag but only one time.

i tried to do that:

```
for tag in $tags
do
    sed -i "/<div id=\"tags\">/a <a href=\"$publicDir\/tags\/$tag\">$tag</a>" $publicDir/index.html
done
```

But that produces that all postLink have all tags.

I only want that a postlink have their tags not the others postLink. Like that:

```
<div class=postLink>
      <a href="asdfa.html"> Write your title here</a>
      <div id="description"> Write the description of the post. It will show in the index.</div>
     <div id="datePost">19-06-2017</div>
     <div id="tags">
        <a href="publicDir/tags/Hellotag"> Hellotag</a>
        <a href="publicDir/tags/Othertag"> Othertag</a>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class=postLink>
      <a href="asdfa.html"> Write your title here</a>
      <div id="description"> Write the description of the post. It will show in the index.</div>
     <div id="datePost">19-06-2017</div>
     <div id="tags">
        <a href="publicDir/tags/Byetag"> Byetag</a>
        <a href="publicDir/tags/Xtag"> Xtag</a>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Sorry my bad english.

Comment: Use a html parser.

Comment: Please show desired output, or tell us which div class should be populated.

Comment: In the last code block is desired output. I want put tags from array only in one postLink without affect other postLink. The links of tags have to be between <div id="tags">  Here the links of tags  </div>.

Comment: I'am not clear about that. It seem's, both `<div id="tags">` are expanded with new tags.

Comment: I want that only one <div id="tags"> is expandend with new tags. If sed can only insert only once time after the first match of <div id="tags">?

Comment: Then I'am a little bit confused, because your desired output has two filled `<div id="tags">`

Comment: No, only one. If i have an  array that contains: tag1 tag2 tagN. The output have to be: <postLink>.... <div id="tags"> <a href="#"> tag1 </a> <a href="#"> tag2 </a> ... <a href="#"> tagN </a>. </div>

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem from oter point of view.
What I do is created a variable called string with the html code "postlink" before where the tags have to be. And then a for loop append tags code and finally add divs ends.

So i have only one "postlink" with the tags, and tags dont affect the previous postlink that could be there before on html page.

```
string="<div class=postLink>\n\t <a href=\"$file.html\">$title</a>\n <div id=\"description\">$description</div>\n<div id=\"datePost\">$date</div>\n<div id=\"tags\">\n"

for tag in $tags
do 
    string+="<a href=\"$publicDir\/tags\/$tag\">$tag</a>\n"
done
string+="</div>\n</div>"

sed -i "/<main>/a $string" "$publicDir/index.html"
```

Thanks John Goofy and 123 for try to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

By using awk and passing the desired text to be printed within the tags div as a variable should achieve what you need. You could use a for loop to construct this variable with different files within the tags directory where required just ensure that you add new lines and tabs where required.

```
awk -v var="\n\t<a href=\"publicDir/tags/Byetag\"\> Byetag</a>\n\t<a href=\"publicDir/tags/Xtag\"> Xtag</a>\n" '{ if ( $0 ~ "tags"  &&  done != 1 ) { print $0var;done=1 } else { printf $0"\n" } }' html
```

Where html is the file in question, we pass the text to be added as a variable called var and then where we find a line that has tags within it (you can "sure up" the reg expression where necessary here) we print the line and the additional text. The variable done is then set to one to ensure that the if statement fails on the next div tag and the text isn't printed.